# Codeigniter - how to make calculation captcha

Tags: php, codeigniter, captcha

I wanted to make a calculation captcha, my current captcha is only a text&number input captcha but it is working just that this captcha is kind of hard so i was thinking to make the captcha easier for login, since the view is like [this(the image here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGjLx.png) which is making the login harder (ignore the userdata for login and focus the line which has captcha on it and please tell me if the code is too long i will try to make it shorter)

Controller

```
public function index(){
        $config = array(
            'img_path'      => 'captcha_images/',
            'img_url'       => base_url().'captcha_images/',
            'img_width'     => '150',
            'img_height'    => 50,
            'word_length'   => 8,
            'font_size'     => 16
        );
        $captcha = create_captcha($config);

        // Unset previous captcha and store new captcha word
        $this->session->unset_userdata('captchaCode');
        $this->session->set_userdata('captchaCode',$captcha['word']);

        // Send captcha image to view
        $data['captchaImg'] = $captcha['image'];

        $data['tampilan'] = $this->m_model->a('judul')->result();
        $this->load->view('login',$data);
    }

    function aksi_login(){
        $data = array('username' => $this->input->post('username', TRUE),
                        'password' => md5($this->input->post('password', TRUE))
        );


        $this->load->model('m_model'); // load model_user
        $hasil = $this->m_model->cek_user($data);
        if ($hasil->num_rows() == 1 && $this->input->post('submit')){
            $inputCaptcha = $this->input->post('captcha');
            $sessCaptcha = $this->session->userdata('captchaCode');
            if($inputCaptcha === $sessCaptcha){
            foreach ($hasil->result() as $sess) {
                $sess_data['logged_in'] = 'Sudah Login';
                $sess_data['id_user'] = $sess->uid;
                $sess_data['username'] = $sess->username;
                $sess_data['level'] = $sess->level;
                $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
            }


            if ($this->session->userdata('level')=='1') {
                redirect('admin');
            }
            elseif ($this->session->userdata('level')=='2') {
                redirect('guru');
            }       
        else {
            redirect('welcome/salah');
        }
    }
    else{
                echo "captcha is wrong";
            }
    }
}
```

view

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url()?>welcome/aksi_login" method="post" class="form">
  <h4> Login </h4>

    <inputtype="text" name="username" placeholder="username"/>

    <input name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"/>


  <a href="<?php echo base_url()?>Welcome" class="refreshCaptcha" ><img src="<?php echo base_url().'asset/foto/refresh.png'; ?>"/></a>
  <p id="captImg"><?php echo $captchaImg; ?></p>
    <inputtype="text" name="captcha" placeholder="Captcha" />


  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in"/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a variable `'word_length' => $var` and on reCaptcha use a smaller number.

Comment: so the word lenght that i have one should be
`'word_length'   => 8`
to `'word_length' => $var`??

Comment: Change it on recaptcha via ajax request or through a hidden field or whatever, don't complicate things so much, if the user got it wrong the first time reduce the number the next time and so on, or make the variable itself rand int between 4~8 as example.

Comment: Lets say the `recaptcha($word_length) { 'word_length' => $word_length; }` or `recaptcha() { 'word_length' => $this->input->post('word_length'); }` and before assigning the value make any operation you need like `$word_length = rand(4,8);` .. i hope you got the idea now.